# Resizing /boot on full disk encryption

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, encryption

I have a 100MB /boot partition and the rest of the disk is fully encrypted.
I want to resize that /boot partition because 100mb is not enough to install selinux/grsecurity. 
I'm using Arch Linux.

How do I resize it without data loss?
Otherwise, would moving /boot to the end of the disk to be able to extend it in the future be fast/secure?

Comment: Attempting to modify the starting sector of a parition is not someting you should be doing if you don't already know how to do it.  That is the only way you will be able to extend your 100 MB partition if it exists before your existing system partition.  You are better of doing an sector-by-sector image of the partition,  removing the partition and extend the 100 MB, then apply the image to the smaller system partition you create. Attempting to change the starting sector of the system disk yourself, without having done it before in the past,  will result in you being unable to boot to your OS.

Comment: " 
Attempting to modify the starting sector of a parition is not someting you should be doing if you don't already know how to do it." Then how to do it properly? I have a 900GB partition and I don't want to buy a new HDD specifically for copying all this crap on it.

Comment: Before I will even go into that specific detail.  You should do a backup of your data.